# MinGW C++ vs. Visual Studio C++ Console Application Bytecode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, g++

I am currently working on a C++ project that is very dependent on the bytecode type. I read somewhere that .NET Languages run on Microsoft's CLR Virtual Machine. Is this the same for a Visual Studio C++ Console Application? Are MinGW GCC compiled applications the same as VS C++ applications?

**EDIT**
When I say, "Are MinGW GCC compiled applications the same as VS C++ applications?", I mean, "Are the executable file formats structured the same? Are they linked the same? Do they use the same assembly-style compilation methods? Do the share common preprocessing and compilation methods? Et cetera, et cetera.

Comment: Visual C++ is compiled to assembly code. It does not use any intermediate language and has no relation to the .NET CLR by itself. I don't know what you mean with "Are [...] applications the same as [...] applications?" - do you mean whether they compile to the same kind of executable? Whether they use the same calling conventions? Whether they link to the same libraries? Whether they are binary compatible? Or whether they will compile to bit-by-bit identical executables?

Comment: @MaxLanghof The question was edited.

Comment: The answer is no, even the files compiled by different versions of VC++ are incompatible.